# $S_7$ cannot be written as a union of fewer than $459$ cyclic subgroups.

Tags: abstract-algebra, symmetric-groups

> Prove that $S_7$ cannot be written as a union of fewer than $459$ cyclic subgroups.

I have no idea about this. I know that $S_7$ has $7!$ elements. However, this has not been helpful. 
We have not learned about Sylow yet.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you mean $S_7$ has $7!$ elements

Comment: See tabulation at http://oeis.org/A218958

Comment: @J.W.Tanner you are correct! Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$S_7$ has elements of order $12$, $10$, $7$, $6$, $5$, $4$, $3$, $2$, and $1$.
We need not care for the only element of order $1$ as it will be covered by any cyclic subgroup. An element of order $2$ consists of one, two, or three two-cycles. In each case, it is a power of an element of higher order:
$$ (1\,2)=\bigl((1\,2)(3\,4\,5)\bigr)^3,\quad (1\,2)(3\,4)=(1\,3\,2\,4)^2,\quad (1\,2)(3\,4)(5\,6)=(1\,3\,5\,2\,4\,6)^3.$$
Hence elements of order two will automatically be covered once we handle those higher orders.
The same argument works for order $3$:
$$(1\,2\,3)=\bigl((1\,3\,2)(4\,5)\bigr)^2, \quad (1\,2\,3)(4\,5\,6)=(1\,4\,2\,5\,3\,6)^2 $$
and *partially* for order $4$:
$$(1\,2\,3\,4)=\big((1\,4\,3\,2)(5\,6\,7)\bigr)^3. $$
However $(1\,2\,3\,4)(5\,6)$ is not the power of an element of higher order. Hence we do need the cyclic groups of order $4$ generated by elements of this form. There are ${7\choose 4}\cdot 3!\cdot {3\choose 2}$ elements of this form, but each cyclic group of order $4$ has two possible generators. Hence we need 
$$ \frac12{7\choose 4}\cdot 3!\cdot {3\choose 2}=315$$
cyclic groups of order $4$.

Order $5$ can  again be ignored:
$$(1\,2\,3\,4\,5)=\bigl((1\,4\,2\,5\,3)(6\,7) \bigr)^2.$$

For order six we have
$$(1\,2\,3)(4\,5)(6\,7)=\bigl((1\,3\,2)(4\,5\,5\,7)\bigr)^2,$$
but $(1\,2\,3)(4\,5)$ and $(1\,2\,3\,4\,5\,6)$ are not such powers. There are ${7\choose 3}2!{4\choose 2}$ elements of the first type and ${7\choose 6}5!$ of the second type. As each cyclic group of order $6$ has two possible generators, we need to use
$$\frac12\left({7\choose 3}2!{4\choose 2}+{7\choose 6}5!\right)= 630$$
cyclic groups of order $6$.

Elements of orer $7$ are all of the form $(1\,2\,3\,4\,5\,6\,7)$ and are not powers of higher-order elements. There are $6!$ such elelemts and each cyclic group of oredr $7$ has $6$ generators, hence we need
$$\frac{6!}6=120 $$
cyclic groups of order $7$.

Elements of order $10$ look like $(1\,2\,3\,4\,5)(6\,7)$, there are ${7\choose 5}4!$ such elements, each cyclic group of order $10$ has $\phi(10)=4$ generators, hence we need
$$ \frac14{7\choose 5}4!=126$$
cyclic groups of order $10$.

Finally, elements of order $12$ look like $(1\,2\,3\,4)(5\,6\,7)$, there are ${7\choose 4}3!2!$ of them, and each group has $\phi(12)=4$ generators, hence we need
$$ \frac14{7\choose 4}3!2!=105$$
cyclic subgroups of order $12$.
In total, we need at least
$$ 315+630+120+126+105=1296$$
cyclic subgroups to cover $S_7$. As $1296>459$, the claim follows.

---

For convenience, here's a short and simple argument showing the original weak claim directly:

The maximal order of an element of $S_7$ is $12$. Hence any cyclic subgroup of $S_7$ has at most $11$ non-neutral elements. Hence $458$ cyclic subgroups together cover at most $11\cdot 458=5038$ non-neutral elements - but $S_7$ has $7!-1=5039$ non-neutral elements!

Comment: I wonder why the question was stated with 459 in it.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I believe that the question just provided a random number. It was provoking the 1296 cyclic subgroups and just asked in this way.

Comment: I supposed there might be simpler argument (e.g., using pigeon-hole) for the weaker claim, but coul dnot find any - until this morning